# Python: bind a function to a key

Tags: python, readline, tab-completion

I just started learning python and am writing my own tab-completion function for practice/fun (so no one tell me to us rlcompleter).  I'm having some trouble getting actually get the python to call the function though.  My code:

```
import readline
def tab_completer():
    print readline.get_line_buffer()

readline.parse_and_bind("tab: tab_completer")
while True:
    raw_input("Prompt")
```

the expected output is that when I hit the tab key it would print what ever I had typed, how ever this is not what is actually happening, any advice?

Comment: You need to detail what is actually happening.

Comment: Nothing happens, something is bound to the tab button (because it no longer tabs), but it doesn't run the function. All that happens is I hear noise like I pressed an invalid key.